# Extracting values from JSON Array of JSON Objects using Argonaut Lenses

Tags: scala, scalaz, lenses, argonaut

It's my first time using argonauts and only have a small knowledge of lenses (enough to get by). I've spent a while trying to figure out the problem myself but getting nowhere.

I'm trying to build a lens to get a JsonArray (of Strings) from some JSON. I can get as far as the Object that has the Array but not sure what to do from there.

The JSON looks like:

[image: json example]

And my lens so far is this:

```
val hashtagsView = twitterEntitiesView >=> jsonObjectPL("hashtags") >=> jArrayPL
```

I'm not sure if that `jArrayPL` is correct either. What I would like to do is just retrieve the text from the Array.

So to wrap up, can anyone help me in finding out how to construct a lens that looks into hashtags and then for each element of the array look into the text, finally getting a values as a `JsonArray`.

**Update:**

With some help from Travis I have the following code compiling:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import monocle.std.list._, monocle.function.Each.each, monocle.function.Index.index
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val \/-(json) = Parse.parse(rawJSON)
val lens = jObjectPrism
          .composeOptional(index("hashtags"))
          .composePrism(jArrayPrism)
          .composeTraversal(each[List[Json], Json])
          .composePrism(jObjectPrism)
          .composeOptional(index("text"))
          .composePrism(jStringPrism)

println(lens.getAll(json))
```

Unfortunately, I get a runtime error: `scalaz.Scalaz$.ToEitherOps(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscalaz/syntax/EitherOps;` starting at the line `val \/-(json) = Parse.parse(rawJSON)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you willing to use the [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) lenses that Argonaut provides instead of the Scalaz lenses? If so, working with traversals is a lot nicer:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import monocle.function.{ each, index }, monocle.std.list._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val doc = """{
  "hashtags": [
    { "indices": [0, 3], "text": "foo" },
    { "indices": [3, 6], "text": "bar" }
  ]
}"""

val \/-(json) = Parse.parse(doc)

val lens = jObjectPrism
  .composeOptional(index("hashtags"))
  .composePrism(jArrayPrism)
  .composeTraversal(each[List[Json], Json])
  .composePrism(jObjectPrism)
  .composeOptional(index("text"))
  .composePrism(jStringPrism)
```

And then:

```
scala> lens.getAll(json)
res0: List[argonaut.Argonaut.JsonString] = List(foo, bar)

scala> lens.modify(_ + " (new)")(json).spaces2
res1: String =
{
  "hashtags" : [
    {
      "indices" : [
        0,
        3
      ],
      "text" : "foo (new)"
    },
    {
      "indices" : [
        3,
        6
      ],
      "text" : "bar (new)"
    }
  ]
}
```

And so on. You could do something similar with Scalaz lenses but it would take more work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Travis. Can I clarify if this is pseudo code or if it should be runnable? The reason I'm asking is that I can't get it to run myself. Here's a pastebin of the error I'm getting back: http://pastebin.com/UbdXjd3F

I'm using Monocle version 1.2.0, Scalaz version 7.0.6 and Argonaut version 6.0.4. Hopefully there's no dependency issue.

Comment: @FintahH It's a real REPL session, but with Argonaut 6.1, which uses a different Monocle version with a slightly different package arrangement. I'm not at a computer at the moment but can give the proper imports for 6.0.4 later.

Comment: @FintanH Oh, sorry, I was wrong—the Monocle lenses weren't available at all in 6.0.4.

Comment: Right! So I just updated to 6.1 because I saw the update while I was exploring the only part of the example I can't get working now is the `each` and `index` functions as they say they're not in that package.

Comment: Was able to compile but got a runtime error. Updated the post.

Comment: @FintanH It sounds like you're somehow bringing in versions of Scalaz and/or Monocle that aren't 7.1.1 and 1.1.0.

Comment: Ya you're right, finally got the dependencies solved. SBT doesn't seem helpful in that regard, but maybe I just need to get used to it. Finally got it all working; thanks a lot!

Comment: we removed the package objects in monocle 1.2, this means in 1.1 you can import index via: `monocle.function.index` while in 1.2 you need `monocle.function.Index.index`. A similar change applies to the mega import, `monocle.function._` (1.1) but `monocle.function.all._` (1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only want to extract the fields:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val doc = """{
  "hashtags": [
    { "indices": [0, 3], "text": "foo" },
    { "indices": [3, 6], "text": "bar" }
  ]
}"""

val \/-(json) = Parse.parse(doc)
val lense = jObjectPL
val hashtags = (lense >=> jsonObjectPL("hashtags") >=> jArrayPL).get(json)

hashtags.get.foreach(i => (lense >=> jsonObjectPL("indices") ).get(i).get.println )
hashtags.get.foreach(i => (lense >=> jsonObjectPL("text") ).get(i).get.println )
```

..or better

```
val ind = ((v:Json) =>(lense >=> jsonObjectPL("indices") ).get(v).get)
val text = ((v:Json) =>(lense >=> jsonObjectPL("text") ).get(v).get)

hashtags.get.foreach(i => (ind(i), text(i)).println )
```